# Empty space under the footer in android default browser

Tags: android, google-chrome, webkit

i have experienced many times that error. There is no such error in FF and Chrome for android, but in default android browser in portratir mode, when footer is sticked to bottom part, and page content height is less than 100%. It shows white line under footer, it seems it's not any padding or margin of Body and HTML, it seems it's something other.

I can use developer tools on desctop to debug Chrome in android, but i don't know how to debug default andoird browser.

I have removed screenshot and link. Because there is no problem anymore.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Problem dissapeared after i have decreased min-width to be 980 from 1000px. 
It seems min-height worked wrong in android and iphone default browsers because of wide width. For example you can took this examples of sticky footer, change min-width of body to be 1000-1040px  and you will see empty space under footer.

Sticky footer example http://ryanfait.com/sticky-footer/